# Query items between x and y with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So, I am using the official Hacker News API and it is hosted on Firebase.

The problem I am having is that I want to get a subset of a list basically.

Something along the way of.
    let topNewsRef = firebase.childByAppendingPath("topstories").queryLimitedToFirst(UInt(batchSize + offset)).queryLimitedToLast(UInt(batchSize))

[I know this does not work but I would like this effect]. Basically I want a subset of a set, specified by a range; from item 2 to item 15, for example].

Say I want 50 items from the 75th item, but the above is not working. So the question is; how do I achieve the same effect?

For example; given a list of 100 items in Firebase. I want all item from the 50th and 75th. There is no property that gives away the order of the items.

Here is my current solution;

```
        let topNewsRef = firebase.childByAppendingPath("topstories").queryLimitedToFirst(UInt(batchSize + offset))
    var handle: UInt?
    handle = topNewsRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
        if let itemIDs = snapshot.value as? [Int] {
            itemIDs.dropFirst(offset) // This drops all items id I already fetched ...
            for itemID in itemIDs {
                let itemRef = self.firebase.childByAppendingPath("item/\(itemID)")
                var itemHandle: UInt?
                itemHandle = itemRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
                    if let itemHandle = itemHandle {
                        itemRef.removeObserverWithHandle(itemHandle)
                    }

                    if let json = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject],
                        // Handle JSON ...
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        if let handle = handle {
            topNewsRef.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
        }
    } // offset += batchSize
```

... which is gettting all items from the start (offset) to the end (batchSize + offset), then I drop the first end of the list by the size of offset. Thus leaving on the list with a size of batchSize left.

Comment: You don't call any `queryOrderedBy...`, which is what the examples in the Firebase docs all do: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries It that's not the problem, then "is not working" is incredibly broad. What does it do? What did you expect it to do? I might also be useful if you show the block that observes and handles the event type.

Comment: queryLimitedToFirst() and queryLimitedToLast() can't be used in tandem. Use one or the other. You're looking for startAt() and endAt(), which work with queryOrderedBy*()

Comment: You need to read my question again. Both of you.

I cannot query by any order since the data is already ordered and it is not under my control. There is no property (such as an id) or anything else like that.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Regardless, I took a stab at it in this [example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1wB8dnA4bcbjIPHxOG7?p=preview). I realize this is in JavaScript, but maybe it will be of help. Is something this along the lines of what you are trying to do? To summarize, I am getting the `/topstories` two at a time, downloading the value of the `/item` that the `topstory` references, and pushing a listener for the `/topstories`.

Comment: It seems to be working. The values for the items are updated when they update in the Firebase instance. The query in javascript is `var query = ref.orderByKey().startAt(''+$scope.options.offset).endAt(''+($scope.options.offset+$scope.options.batchSize-1));` -- integers are changed to strings because `startAt()` and `endAt()` arguments need to be strings when used with `orderByKey()`.

Comment: That is what I want to do. The problem is that with the iOS SDK for Firebase the startAt() and endAt() method do not exist. They would solve my 'problem'.

Comment: Yeah, so the real question I guess is; 'How do I implement a query like 'ref.startAt(15).endAt(20)' but in the iOS SDK. :)

Comment: How about [`.queryOrderedByKey`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/queryOrderedByKey) used in combination with `queryStartingAtValue:`, `queryEndingAtValue:`

Comment: The starting and ending values are basically unknown. I only know the index of the items. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87680/discussion-between-sinan-bolel-and-entalpi).

Comment: @Kato, I am not sure if the iOS documentation mentions that `queryStartingAtValue:` and `queryEndingAtValue:` need the arguments to be strings when combined with `.queryOrderedByKey`. The JavaScript docs do mention that "When used in combination with orderByKey(), the value must be a string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was solved with the following query.

```
firebase.childByAppendingPath("topstories").queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue(String(offset)).queryEndingAtValue(String(offset + batchSize - 1))
```

The thing is that the Firebase documentation does not specify that the "AnyObject!" parameters can be used as indices on the query. They also forget to mention that the indices should be of type String.

Comment: Check my edit above -- don't forget to subtract 1 from the endingValue (or add 1 to the next offset). Otherwise you will run into an off-by-one bug.

Answer (score 3):

Following our comments to your question,

You can use [`.queryOrderedByKey`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FQuery.html#//api/name/queryOrderedByKey) in combination with `queryStartingAtValue:`, `queryEndingAtValue:`

The data in `/topstories` is stored as an array. when ordering by key, the indices of the objects in the array are the keys. Then, all you need to do is cast the `offset` and `batchSize` as strings and pass them to  `queryStartingAtValue:` & `queryEndingAtValue:` like so:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue(String(offset)).queryEndingAtValue(String(offs‌​et+batchSize-1));
```

- Don't forget to subtract 1 for the endingValue if you are incrementing offset by batchsize.
- For the nth query in the series,

  - `startingAtIndex = initialOffset + (batchSize * (n - 1))`
  - `endingAtIndex = initialOffset + (batchSize * n) - 1`
- For example, let `batchSize`=100 and the initial `offset`=0.

  - The first 100 items are keys 0 through 99. The `key` (index) of the first item in the array is `0`.
  - If you query for `endingAt(offset+batchSize)`, you will be ending at index 100, which is the 101st item in the array.
  - Thus, you will be getting 101 items -- one more than your batch size.
  - the second query will then be for items with indices 100-199 (starting at 0+batchsize and ending at 0+batchsize+batchsize-1), which is 100 items.

Here is an [example PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1wB8dnA4bcbjIPHxOG7?p=preview) of the same concept implemented in JavaScript.

:)